# Rails enum returning integer value in Sidekiq Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

We receive error reports with our enum types only when run in Sidekiq jobs. I'm not sure if it's for every run or random runs, but we'll commonly get errors like these:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for 1:Integer Did you mean?
>   to_s

```
enum status: [:active, :inactive, :deleted]

def set_status
  return if self.status.to_sym == :deleted
  ...
end
```

Comment: `return if self.status.to_sym == :deleted` should be `return if deleted?`. You should use the magic methods provided by the enum, not work directly with the field.

Comment: thanks @meagar ! - we'll review these spots in our code and report back for future searches.

Comment: @meagar you're correct that these do work. but it seems to be a missing implementation detail for support of the enum type, doesn't it?

Comment: Nevermind that would create a dependency on Rails for a really specific case, which it doesn't really need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as an answer, so this question can be marked as closed:

`return if self.status.to_sym == :deleted` should be `return if deleted?`. You should use the magic methods provided by the enum, not work directly with the field.

Sidekiq is a processor for Ruby, so introducing this would create an unncessary dependency on Rails.

Of course this is my opinion, but after thinking through this Rails should be the one handling numbers equivalently with their respective symbolized forms. For example, you can set `status` to 0, :active, or 'active', and it saves appropriately but the value returned during get should be consistent or methods provided to ensure consistency.